# When i refresh the application server side validation messages are not hiding in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a login jsp page. i am doing server side validations for that login page using java servlets. When i click on login button without entering the values it is showing error messages. After that i am just refreshing that login page even though that error messages are still displaying.

My requirement is when i refresh and when i come back from the forwarded page , my login page which contains error messages should not display.

Here is my code

```
if(username==null || username.isEmpty()){
                             errors.put("username", "Please Enter User Name");
                             }
                             if(password==null || password.isEmpty()){
                                 errors.put("password", "Please Enter Password");
                                 }
                             if(type==null || type.isEmpty()){
                                 errors.put("type", "Please Select Type");
                                 }

                             if(errors.size()>0)
                                {
                                 request.setAttribute("map",errors);
                                 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                                 rd.forward(request, response);

                               }
```

JSP

```
<%!
    Map<String,String> errors=null;

%>
 <%
      if(request.getAttribute("map")!=null){
       errors=(Map<String,String>)request.getAttribute("map");
       request.removeAttribute("map");
      }
    %>



<div class="textbox">
    <%if(request.getParameter("username")== null || "".equals(request.getParameter("username"))){ %>
    <input name="username" type="text"/>
    <span style="color:red"><%=(errors!=null?(errors.get("username")!=null?errors.get("username"):""):"")%></span>
    <%} else{ %>
    <input name="username" type="text" value="<%=request.getParameter("username")%>"/>
   <%} %> 
   </div>
    <div class="Password">Password</div>
    <div class="textbox">
    <%if(request.getParameter("password")== null || "".equals(request.getParameter("password"))){ %>
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <span style="color:red"><%=(errors!=null?(errors.get("password")!=null?errors.get("password"):""):"")%></span>
    <%} else{ %>
    <input name="password" type="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
    <%} %> 
    </div>
    <div class="Password">Type</div>
    <div class="type"> 
           <%if(request.getParameter("type")== null || "".equals(request.getParameter("type"))){ %>
        <select name="type" id="type">
            <option value="">---Select---</option>
            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
            <option value="User">User</option>
           <!--  <option></option>
            <option></option> -->
        </select>
        <span style="color:red"><%=(errors!=null?(errors.get("type")!=null?errors.get("type"):""):"")%></span>
        <%} else{ %>
        <select name="type" id="type">
            <option value="<%=request.getParameter("type")%>"><%=request.getParameter("type")%></option>
            <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
            <option value="User">User</option>
           <!--  <option></option>
            <option></option> -->
        </select>
        <%} %> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you are not clearing `errors` map while refreshing page.

Comment: How to clear that errors

Comment: By refreshing, you're simply sending the exact same request as the one sent when submitting the form. So the validation is triggered again, and error messages are displayed again. This is expected and normal.